# TFS - Changing Description field Datatype

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

In TFS, what the consequences of changing the Description field's datatype from HTML to Plaintext?

Comment: Hi Adegoke A, any update on this , did my reply explained  clearly? If this figured out your confusion, appreciate for marking as the answer.

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for your answer. The answer I was looking for was basically a 'No' but thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> HTML
>
> Supports the ability to capture **rich-text data** and to **use
>   longer text descriptions** such as the Description or Repro Steps
>   fields. **An HTML field differs from a PlainText field in that an HTML
>   field is strongly typed to HTML for richer displays of information.**
>   HTML fields are automatically indexed for full-text search when
>   full-text search is available. See [Full-Text and partial word
>   searches](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/track/query-operators-variables#full-text).

There are just different field data type. The field data type determines the kind and size of data that you can store in the field. A field can have only one type defined within a team project collection.

> PlainText
>
> Supports entry of a text string that can contain more than 255 Unicode
>   characters, such as the Title field. These fields are automatically
>   indexed for full-text search, when full-text search is available.

More details about the field, please refer this: [Field data types and attributes](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/reference/define-modify-work-item-fields)